# How to run mypy having local stubs directory at pre-commit?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have separate directory for local stubs named `stubs` and at configuration file, I have set `mypy_path=stubs`.

When I run from command line `mypy`, it passes successfuly.
But at pre-commit it is throwing error.

`pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.mypy]
python_version = "3.8"
mypy_path = 'stubs'
files  = 'project_files/*.py'
warn_return_any = true
warn_unused_configs = true
```

`.pre-commit-config.yml`,

```
-   repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.910
    hooks:
    -   id: mypy
        entry: mypy 
        verbose: true
        args: []
        additional_dependencies: [pandas-stubs==1.1.0.11]
```

I am getting this error `Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named 'boto3'` though I haved added the implementation at `stubs`.

How can I make mypy consistent between pre-commit and CLI?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, I have a `stubs/boto3.pyi` and it works correctly for me -- please add more information

Comment: Adding  `mypy_path = $MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR/stubs` solves my issue.